# Mouse cursor in VNC jumps

Tags: linux, qt, embedded, vnc

Started an X11VNC server on my embedded linux device and connect with a VNC client (TigerVNC or Guacamole). The VNC server streams directly the framebuffer to port 5901. The cursor jumps badly when moved over the GUI ([see video](https://youtu.be/0Setz2nZlP4)).

[image]

```
x11vnc -rfbport 5901 -no6 -rawfb /dev/fb0 -scale 640x480x16x1280 -verbose -cursor none -nodragging -pipeinput UINPUT:direct_abs=/dev/uinput
```

tried lots of additional parameters without success: -pointer_mode n -extra_fbur n -visual TrueColor:32 -noshm

Comment: Workaround: Starting the qt program with parameter `-platform vnc` resulted in a usable experience. Don't know yet if multiple platforms at the same time are possible. e.g. run vnc on top of framebuffer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the problem was in the default acceleration.

[see documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/1/x11vnc)

> Note: the default acceleration is 2.0 since it seems
> both X and qt-embedded often (but not always) use this value.

so the edited x11vnc command includes **accel=1.0**:

```
x11vnc -rfbport 5901 -no6 -rawfb /dev/fb0 -verbose -cursor none -nodragging -pipeinput UINPUT:direct_abs=/dev/uinput,accel=1.0 -forever
```